# Lexer and Parser Generators for Common Lisp

Tags: parsing, common-lisp, lex

Can you recommend lexer and parser generators for Common Lisp? I have seen the following lists on CLiki, but most on the lists seem to be in their alpha stages:

- http://www.cliki.net/LEXER
- http://www.cliki.net/parser%20generator

So it would be helpful if you could share your good or bad experience with any of them or recommend other alternatives. I prefer a tool which is similar to traditional lex/yacc tools for other languages, but other approaches will be also welcome.

Comment: I used cl-yacc and cl-lex

Answer (score 3):

There is [smug](https://github.com/drewc/smug) ([documentation](http://common-lisp.net/~dcrampsie/smug.html)), which provides "functional" parsers that are supposedly similar to some of Haskell's parsing libraries.

Also, if you're looking for Lex/Yacc style parsing, look into [lispbuilder](http://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/Welcome), which has lexer and yacc packages that seem mature.

Comment: @user1628266, was my answer helpful and correct? If it was, please accept it (click the outline of the check mark) so everyone knows that this is the answer to your question.