# Parsing and generating text in Common LISP

Tags: common-lisp, text-parsing

I would like to find a library for parsing and generating text in common lisp. I would like it to be maintained and documented and preferably with a community that could answer questions.

In the past I have used for the same job ANTLR/StringTemplate in Java and Boost.Spirit in C++. Both projects are well documented in my opinion. From what I am reading, Parsec for Haskell would also meet my requirements. But I have not found something similar for LISP. Perhaps lispers parse texts using their own hand-made parsers?

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273892/lexer-and-parser-generators-for-common-lisp), but the so-called documentation on smug is a technical report on monadic parsing, with examples in Haskell. The documentation of LispBuilder looks rather short also. Most projects in CLiki seem abandoned.

Which library would you recommend? The grammar I need to parse is not very complicated.

Comment: I think there is a .Net version of ANTLR. Perhaps it would integrate well with your C++ depending on your compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a look at

- [Cl-yacc](http://www.cliki.net/cl-yacc)
- [Esrap](https://github.com/nikodemus/esrap)

Comment: CL-yacc worked for me, basically because the docs are usable and it allows you to easily define precedence rules. http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/cl-yacc/cl-yacc.html